# Can't figure out how to put contents of txt file into 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm working on a data structures and algorithms problem for a class I am taking.

I am asked to put the contents of a .txt file into a 2d array and find the lowest value and the number of times it appears in the array. The .txt file contains a large number of sets of numbers ranging from 20000-120000.

29432, 113244, 96324...etc..

Here is the code I have.

```
class A1_Part1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final int SIZE = 10000; 
        int count = 0;
        int[][] elevations = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

        final String filename = "src/ELEVATIONS.TXT";
        File file= new File(filename);
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);

        while (fileInput.hasNextLine() && count < elevations.length) {
            elevations[count][0] = fileInput.nextInt();
//            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(elevations));
            count++;
        }

        int[][] numbers = Arrays.copyOf(elevations, count); 
        fileInput.close();

            int[] result = getMin(numbers);
            System.out.printf("%d is the lowest elevation and appears %d times",
                    +result[0], result[1]);

        }

    public static int[] getMin(int[][] numbers) {
        int minValue = numbers[0][0];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length ; j++) {
                if (numbers[i][j] < minValue)
                    minValue = numbers[i][j];
                else if (numbers[i][j] == minValue)
                    count++;
            }
        }return new int[]{minValue, count};


    }
```

When I run the program,  I get the answers 0 and 999999999.
I realize that I am only getting the result of min value as 0 because when I print the array using the Arrays.deepToString method I get nothing but millions of 0's.  It looks like the code is just making a blank array full of 100 million 0s.

I've been trying a ton of different things to solve this but I cannot get the contents of the file into the array for processing with the getMin method.  I thought that the while loop would step through the array and add the values of the .txt file to the elevations array but its not doing that.

I am not allowed to use ArrayList for this problem, hence why I have count and arrays.copyOf in the main method to get the actual size of the array.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do the first 5 lines of ELEVATIONS.TXT look like? Also, to debug this, temporarily change `SIZE = 10` or maybe even 3. Place a breakpoint on the `count++` line and inspect your 2d array. This way you will see what is going on. Finally, note that in `elevations[count][0] = fileInput.nextInt();` you are not incrementing the second dimension. It's always `0`.

Comment: The first 5 lines looks like:
30155 77655 30054 40100 20690 42850 87875 36904 92785 77712 46938 36564 etc...

If i change size to 10 it just shows me the count as 99 (array if size 100)

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise in my request. Please put lines in your question, in a code block. I'm trying figure out how you are supposed to get a 2d array out of the data. Are there two numbers on each line, only two lines in the file, or ...? Show the first few lines of the data file in you question. Use the triple back tick formatting that is used for code blocks. Also, did you run the code and inspect the value of `elevations` at the breakpoint on `count++`? You should realize there's a flaw in your thinking by stepping through the code at that point.